# Exchange 2016 Remove Autocomplete Entry for All Users in Domain

Tags: exchange

I would like to remove an autocomplete entry for all Exchange users in the company.
An important address is moving to another mailbox and we want to avoid that users get error messages when using the existing autocomplete entry.
The alternative is just that we inform the users about the move and hope that they get the entry deleted by hand.
[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-suggested-recipients-in-the-to-cc-and-bcc-boxes-with-auto-complete-dbe46e31-c098-4881-8cf7-66b037bce23e#:~:text=Turn%20off%20the%20Auto%2DComplete,and%20Bcc%20lines%20check%20box](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-suggested-recipients-in-the-to-cc-and-bcc-boxes-with-auto-complete-dbe46e31-c098-4881-8cf7-66b037bce23e#:%7E:text=Turn%20off%20the%20Auto%2DComplete,and%20Bcc%20lines%20check%20box).

Such a case has also been described here, however I can't get the script to run on Exchange 2016.

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1836616-removing-single-outlook-autocomplete-entry-from-all-users

I hope someone has an idea about this!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found any solutions on Exchange server side. Maybe you can try to delete the local cache for outlook users if it is convenient.

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1976362-remove-autocomplete-from-exchange-directly

Comment: Thank you.
I see from the comments from https://eightwone.com/2014/07/17/clearing-autocomplete-and-other-recipient-caches/ that removing a single address is apparently not possible via script.